# How to improve GPT2 tokenizer trained from scratch?

Tags: nlp, tokenization

I trained a GPT2 Tokenizer on Hindi dataset of size 170 MB from scratch and saved it as new_tokenizer. When I tried the new_tokenizer on a Hindi sentence

`मेरा नाम विनय है`

The number of tokens generated are 12 which are as follows

`['म', 'े', 'र', 'ा', ' न', 'ा', 'म', ' व', 'ि', 'न', 'य', ' ह', 'ै']`

I experimented with vocab size = 300, 500, 1000, 5000. In none of the cases new_tokenizer was able to capture complete words. How can I improve my tokenizer?

````
from transformers import GPT2TokenizerFast

# validate the changes
text = "मेरा नाम विनय है"
new_tokenizer = GPT2TokenizerFast.from_pretrained("new_tokenizer_gpt2")

encoded_tokens = new_tokenizer.encode(text)
print(encoded_tokens)
print([new_tokenizer.decode(input_id) for input_id in encoded_tokens])
```
````

Comment: The vocabulary size for subword tokenizers for LM's of the size of GPT-2 tend to be in around 30k. Maybe you should try with a vocabulary of that size.

Comment: @noe I also tried with vocab size = 30K and 50K, but getting same results.

Comment: Maybe it's related with the presence of matras, as described in [this issue](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/12828) and [this other issue](https://github.com/huggingface/tokenizers/issues/572).